# Hiding Q*BoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have a dialog box with 2 radio buttons. Each should be connected to a Q*BoxLayout (some content in it), so when the user presses first one, it should show the first Layout with its content, if the user chooses second one, it should display (or enable the visibility) of the second, but I cannot hide an entire layout

Is it possible to hide it?

If no, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the content of the boxlayout inside a QWidget. Then add suitable boxlayout to the QWidget. Now you can hide and show that container widget.

Comment: I tried that with no success. After I created .h and .cpp files of custom widget, how do I add it in designer widget list (I know it is offtopic)

Comment: Ok, I finally got it how to promote :)

Comment: @khajvah As hyde already said, you do not need to create a custom widget if you only want it to act as a container to other widgets. The plain QWidget will do fine.